# Socket.io client-side doesn't show execution errors in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

Sorry for my english
On the client side I have something like this

```
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io(servHost);

socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log(`Connected : ${socket.id}`);
        
    socket.emit('join', "Some data");
    socket.emit('otherEvent');

  });

 socket.on('disconnect', (err) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log("Disconnected");
});
```

if I have a execution errors inside any socket.on the client disconnects and reconnects to the server without showing any type of error
An exaggerated example

```
socket.on('connect', () => {
    console.log(`Connected : ${socket.id}`);
    const mistake = null;
    mistake.onPurpose = "this is wrong"; 

    socket.emit('join', "Some data");
    socket.emit('otherEvent');

  });
```

Client log:

```
Connected : IyR4Gr0Gvao16UD6AAAD
parse error
Disconnected
Connected : m8aSe6HI67i6VIBNAAAF
parse error
Disconnected
...
```

I guess that parse error refers to that execution error I made on purpose

how can i get normal javascript execution error messages?
something like  Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onPurpose') at line x:y...

im already tried with

```
localStorage.debug = '*';
```

but nothing happened

Comment: Socket.io probably has an error event you can listen to.

Comment: yes, i tried with    
`sock.on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(err); // prints the message associated with the error
    });`


but nothing happened

Comment: I tried with     `sock.on("connect_error", (err) => {
        console.log(err.message); // prints the message associated with the error
    });` to and nothing

Answer (score 0):

A fix I found that I'm not happy with and I'm sure there's a better way to fix it is to put a try catch inside every function like this...

```
socket.on('connect', () => {
    try{
       console.log(`Connected : ${socket.id}`);
       const mistake = null;
       mistake.onPurpose = "this is wrong"; 

       socket.emit('join', "Some data");
       socket.emit('otherEvent');
    }catch(error){
     console.log(error);
    }
  });
```